# How to adjust area text bounding box without altering kerning or spacing between words?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am creating svg figures using ggplot in R, then fine-tuning them in Adobe Illustrator.

Any attempt to expand area text in Illustrator (i.e. plot title or axis labels) causes the words to be spaced further apart.

How can I keep the word spacing constant while increasing the size of the area text bounding box, so that all the text can be seen?

The images show what happens when I try to expand the text box.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be a problem with the bounding boxes drawn by the graphics device in R Studio. It cannot be undone by Illustrator.

The simplest (though non-reproducible) solution is just to delete the text box in Illustrator and add a new one manually, then type your text. It is fast and if you insist on reproducible work it is necessary to learn the ins and outs of the `theme` arguments in `ggplot` to specify the sizes. I also recommend the `latex2expr` package for typing LaTeX math notation into `ggplot` arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Increase Letter Spacing to fit the text your desired need. Let me know if you have any questions.

[image: Illustration Screenshot]